# Crosstab Data is empty when using a Java Bean Data Source?

Tags: jasper-reports, javabeans

I have a problem in jasper reports using **Java Bean Data Source** using Data Source Expression in crosstab as `$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}`

I can successfully populate data in detail section,

but when I try to use the bean data in crosstab; the crosstab is empty on preview.

Anyone who knows what to do on this particular setup?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}` is the JDBC database connection, since you are using a "Java Bean Datasource", you should not pass the database connection but instead a `JRDatasource`.

Passing a datasource to a crosstab is done by specifying the `dataSourceExpression`

```
<crosstabDataset>
    <dataset>
        <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="bcc868c0-ea35-4a17-b570-2d51dbe93e8d">
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
        </datasetRun>
    </dataset>
</crosstabDataset>
```

### *However,*

If you like to use the current main report datasource (as above) you can simply not specify any dataset nor a connection, this will automatically use main datasource and there is no need to define a subDataset.

### *but*,

You need to be careful, the `JRDatasource` is "consumed" when the it fills, hence if you have already used it once (detail band present in jrxml), it is consumed. To understand this better see for example [How to use same JRBeanCollectionDataSource on multiple sub reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54288040/5292302)