# How to create nested table like jasper report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have been trying to create a jasper report which should look like the following image:

[image: desired output]

For my sample report, **Out-1** and **Out-2** are rows for the outer table and **asd**, **asds**, **adasd** are rows for the inner table.

I am trying to achieve it using nested tables. But the table takes the field and I can not assign field to the inner-table.

I am creating jasper reports in Java code rather than using SQL connection to the table for some reason.

### JXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ec55a262-fec4-45f4-9b48-5be98088aafa">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <subDataset name="New Dataset 1" uuid="cdef25ec-abc4-45ba-b70e-28d82716626b">
        <field name="sachNr" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="akundenNr" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="nestedTable" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="New Dataset 2" uuid="eec983aa-a227-4a28-9c44-73cbe31fa024">
        <field name="packStNr" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="prodDatum" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="stueck" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name=" artikeldatenTable" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table" x="0" y="28" width="360" height="50" uuid="fae14075-18a8-4fcc-b6f9-c14e3623e75d"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 1" uuid="17a10558-3a43-47c2-809d-6362924e5015">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(1)]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="137" uuid="7a8ca2ff-7a1a-41a0-8c30-b02f7be6e2b9">
                        <jr:tableHeader height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="137" height="30" uuid="0fe0e502-dea8-45f6-9f96-633f5db90cd8"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sachNr}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell height="42" rowSpan="1">
                            <componentElement>
                                <reportElement key="table" x="0" y="0" width="137" height="42" uuid="9e72ca8c-182d-41c0-a021-98493162c7da"/>
                                <jr:table>
                                    <datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 2" uuid="7475e256-4bc5-4e88-be92-b6d2eb2fd4c5">
                                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                    </datasetRun>
                                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="cd851138-c894-459f-91c9-636c3602b247">
                                        <jr:detailCell height="20" rowSpan="1">
                                            <textField>
                                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="ce21338e-c593-4bae-b7c4-08741127575c"/>
                                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{packStNr}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                            </textField>
                                        </jr:detailCell>
                                    </jr:column>
                                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="5f2b25a9-e34a-4698-b1ab-e8843dafec3c">
                                        <jr:detailCell height="20" rowSpan="1">
                                            <textField>
                                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="5487305d-d22f-46fa-97bc-88e671f7085c"/>
                                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{prodDatum}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                            </textField>
                                        </jr:detailCell>
                                    </jr:column>
                                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="93c28f55-9bda-4be0-989a-03ce573715ba">
                                        <jr:detailCell height="20" rowSpan="1">
                                            <textField>
                                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="53c4e2b3-7591-49b3-9b13-50cc1f16641a"/>
                                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{stueck}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                            </textField>
                                        </jr:detailCell>
                                    </jr:column>
                                </jr:table>
                            </componentElement>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="f898d2e7-1c2f-48fe-9357-61ee5d767a51">
                        <jr:tableHeader height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="16b70095-2900-46f0-96ec-d638edb784f3"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{akundenNr}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell height="42" rowSpan="1"/>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="111" uuid="0121d9c8-d1f0-447f-84ed-15385693a072">
                        <jr:tableHeader height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell height="42" rowSpan="1"/>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="ca27e48c-a1d6-4c32-a1de-2580b6786b3d">
                        <jr:tableHeader height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell height="42" rowSpan="1"/>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

### Outer Table POJO

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;

public class OuterTable {

    private String sachNr;
    private String akundenNr;
    private String SUBREPORT_DIR;
    private JRBeanCollectionDataSource nestedTable;

    public String getSachNr() {
        return sachNr;
    }
    public void setSachNr(String sachNr) {
        this.sachNr = sachNr;
    }
    public String getAkundenNr() {
        return akundenNr;
    }
    public void setAkundenNr(String akundenNr) {
        this.akundenNr = akundenNr;
    }
    public String getSUBREPORT_DIR() {
        return SUBREPORT_DIR;
    }
    public void setSUBREPORT_DIR(String sUBREPORT_DIR) {
        SUBREPORT_DIR = sUBREPORT_DIR;
    }

    public JRBeanCollectionDataSource getNestedTable() {
        return nestedTable;
    }
    public void setNestedTable(JRBeanCollectionDataSource nestedTable) {
        this.nestedTable = nestedTable;
    }

}
```

### Inner Table POJO

```
public class InnerTable {

    private String packStNr;
    private String prodDatum;
    private Integer stueck;

    public String getPackStNr() {
        return packStNr;
    }
    public void setPackStNr(String packStNr) {
        this.packStNr = packStNr;
    }
    public String getProdDatum() {
        return prodDatum;
    }
    public void setProdDatum(String prodDatum) {
        this.prodDatum = prodDatum;
    }
    public Integer getStueck() {
        return stueck;
    }
    public void setStueck(Integer stueck) {
        this.stueck = stueck;
    }

}
```

### My Controller

```
private void generateLagerbestand(List<Artikeldaten> artikelList) throws JRException, FileNotFoundException {
    JasperReport jasperReport;

    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    List <OuterTable> outerTableList = new ArrayList<OuterTable>();
    for(int i = 0; i < artikelList.size(); i++) {


        List <InnerTable> innerTableList = new ArrayList<InnerTable>();
        List<Lager> lagersList = artikelList.get(i).getLagers();
        for(int j = 0; j < lagersList.size(); j++) {

            InnerTable innerTable = new InnerTable();

            innerTable.setPackStNr(lagersList.get(j).getPackstnr());
            innerTable.setProdDatum(lagersList.get(j).getProddatum().toString());
            innerTable.setStueck(lagersList.get(j).getStueck());

            innerTableList.add(innerTable);
        }

        OuterTable outerTable = new OuterTable();

        outerTable.setAkundenNr(artikelList.get(i).getAkundennr());
        outerTable.setSachNr(artikelList.get(i).getSachnr());

        JRBeanCollectionDataSource nestedTable = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(innerTableList);
        outerTable.setNestedTable(nestedTable);

        outerTableList.add(OuterTable);
    }

    try {

        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("PathToMyReport\\MyReport.jrxml");
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource outerTableItems = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(outerTableList);


        // artikeldatenTable is outerTable
        parameters.put("artikeldatenTable", outerTableItems);
        JREmptyDataSource jrEmptyDataSource = new JREmptyDataSource();
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, jrEmptyDataSource);
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("PathToMyPDF:\\MyPDF.pdf"));

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the concept of the detail band, the detail will iterate on the datasource you pass to report

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, jrEmptyDataSource)
```

That's an empty datasource!, it will not iterate at all.

### *Instead, pass*

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource outerTableItems = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(outerTableList);
```

To the report, define the fields of `OuterTable` in your main report (not a subDatasource) including `nestedTable`

```
<field name="nestedTable" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
```

### *Then*

In detail band you put textFields related to first level "Out-1" and "Out-2" in your example.

Bellow you add the `jr:table` component taking the datasource from the bean

```
<datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 1" uuid="17a10558-3a43-47c2-809d-6362924e5015">
      <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{nestedTable}]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

In general within the bean I would not have `JRBeanCollectionDatasource` but instead store the data in a normal `List<>`, the reason is that a JRDatasource is consumable you can only use it once, see this to understand better [How to use same JRBeanCollectionDataSource on multiple sub reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288040/how-to-use-same-jrbeancollectiondatasource-on-multiple-sub-reports/54288395#54288395)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
It made me realize my mistake.
The only thing that I did differently from your answer was to create `List<JRBeanCollectionDatasource>` for `nestedTable`.